# No support for meqrlogit as of Stata 16

Tags: stata

I looked at the help file for `meqrlogit` in Stata 16 and it is no longer part of Stata 16. The alternative found is to use integration method `pcaghermite` in `melogit` but when I used this method I got the error `method pcaghermite not recognized`.

Comment: The help file for `melogit` lists `mcaghermite`, `mvaghermite`, and `ghermite` as options for `intmethod`. Are you sure it's not any of these?

Comment: This [melogit](https://www.stata.com/manuals/me.pdf) help file lists pcaghermite as intmethod.

Comment: See also https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1574253-no-support-for-meqrlogit-as-of-stata-16  Cross-posting -- if that is what this is -- without telling people about it is widely seen as poor practice, leading to wasted time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meqrlogit` still works, but is no longer part of 'official' stata (see `help meqrlogit`)

`melogit` is the recommended replacement.

The following example implements the integration method `pcaghermite`:

```
webuse bangladesh

melogit c_use i.urban age child* || district: i.urban, ///
    cov(unstruct) intmethod(pcaghermite)
```

**Edit** since the issue was updating here is the update check proposed in [the answer on Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1574253-no-support-for-meqrlogit-as-of-stata-16?p=1574809#post1574809):

```
// Check your update status
quietly query update

foreach component in exe ado utilities docs {
    assert r(inst_`component') == r(avbl_`component')
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems the issue is with Stata not up-to-date. The last update on my Stata was in Mar 2020 and this method was introduced after that. I have asked admin to update the Stata and hopefully, it will work.

Comment: I see. When I answered I was not aware of the cross-posting.